# Integrate $\int\exp\left(ax+bx^2\right)x^{\eta}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Consider the following integral:

$$\int\exp\left(ax+bx^2\right)x^{\eta}\mathrm{d}x$$

where $\eta\ge0$ is a real number, and $a$ and $b$ are also real numbers.

Can I express this integral in terms of some special functions, such as the incomplete Gamma function ($\Gamma(x;z_1,z_2) = \int_{z_1}^{z_2} t^{x-1}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$), or some other special function that is computable using standard numerical libraries?

Comment: related (a similar integral): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/645391/10063

Answer (score 0):

If you complete the square using some constant value you multiply & divide from outside the integral, you could write it as the $\eta$ moment of the normal distribution : $$\int x^\eta e^{(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx$$

However to evaluate this you will go through the Gamma function which seems unavoidable.

This is also called the [raw moment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RawMoment.html).

Note : This only works if $\eta\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: What if $\eta$ is a real number? ...

Comment: I missed that out sorry. Incomplete Gamma function is the only way I see.

Comment: Incomplete Gamma function is excellent... but do you have an expression in terms of the incomplete Gamma function? Because I don't see it.

Comment: No nice closed form. I only know hypergeometric series to evaluate it. Follow http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html